# Social media plugins button on my blog

Tags: plugins, post, blogs, facebook-social-plugins

Why is that when I press "like" or "tweet" and even "+1" button on one post of my blog, it is also applied to all post even when I am not pressing the like button on other post. Do you think it is my html/javascript code who gave this problem or bug?

Thank you,

Comment: It might be set for the whole domain instead of a post... try to check the options
Also what blog are you using? blogger? wordpress... ?

Comment: i am using blogger. any idea what should i do about it?

Comment: Can someone help me what should I do to fix this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

first check the og: tags are correctly specified in the HTML.  You can use Facebook's free linter tool to check and ensure they're correct:  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Also, it would be more helpful to us to help you if you provided some sample links and also code you're using to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using blogger, then instead of using the code provided by Facebook(which is static), you have to use a dynamic version which will generate the FBML tags appropriately.Similar is the case with twitter and G+. Here are the links to the those.
Like button : http://www.bloggerplugins.org/2010/04/facebook-like-button-for-blogger.html
G+ Button : http://www.bloggerplugins.org/2011/06/add-google-plus-one-button-on-blogger.html

Comment: and for the tweet Button : http://www.bloggerplugins.org/2010/08/twitter-share-buttons-for-blogger-tweet.html
For any other Social sites you can modify their code appropriately as done in these 3 tutorials.